# onClick Image tick/check the check box

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Check box then a Cross Image as below.

[image]

when i click the Image, the Checkbox should get checked. I have tried the following code. but no use.

```
<img src="common_images/x.png" width="13" height="13" alt="X" onClick="this.chk.checked=true;">
```

Can any one help with the Javascript to accomplish it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try labels and advanced css selectors:

http://jsfiddle.net/eBZQV/1/

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk " checked="checked" id="img1" name="img1" value="0" />
<label for="img1">
    <img class="img" src="https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/41566_188055278014093_1312238546_q.jpg" />
</label>
```

Comment: where & how to place the jquery ?

Comment: the file should be where this html is at, if you make a folder then sub dir like his js/javascript.js

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to accomplish it

```
$('image').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="checkbox"]').click();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nR5Mp/

Comment: where & how to place this jquery ?

Comment: Inside <script> and </script> but you should first add jquery library http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js